# Check blank space or only empty space in text-editor or prime ng p-editor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation, frontend

While submitting form data, text-editor body should not be blank or empty.
User should not be able to submit blank space or empty data.

How to handle such scenario(check noticeText variable request).

Request body/data below:

**example 1 :**

```
noticeText: <p><span class="ql-size-huge"> </span></p>
```

**example 2 :**

```
noticeText: <p> </p>
```

**example 3 :**

```
noticeText: <p><strong class="ql-size-huge"><em> </em></strong></p>
```

**HTML:**

```
    <form [formGroup]="addNoticeForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">     
        <div class="p-fluid p-formgrid p-grid">
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4 p-xl-3">
                <label for="companyRole">Company Role<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <p-multiSelect [class.view-disable]="isViewDisable" placeholder="Select an option" formControlName="companyRole" [(ngModel)]="selectedCompanyRole" [options]="companyRoleOptions"
                        optionLabel="name" optionValue="code" appMultiSelection (onChange)="getSelectedRole(companyRole)"
                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.companyRole.errors?.error }"></p-multiSelect>
                        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.companyRole.errors && p.companyRole.errors?.error">
                            {{p.companyRole.errors?.error}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4 p-xl-3">
                <label for="user">Users<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <p-multiSelect [class.view-disable]="isViewDisable" placeholder="Select an option" formControlName="user" [(ngModel)]="selecteduser" [options]="userOptions"
                        optionLabel="name" optionValue="code" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.user.errors?.error }" appMultiSelection></p-multiSelect>
                <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.user.errors && p.user.errors?.error">
                    {{p.user.errors?.error}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4 p-xl-3">
                <label for="noticeType">Notice type<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <p-dropdown [disabled]="isViewDisable" placeholder="Select an option" formControlName="noticeType" [(ngModel)]="selectedNoticeType" [options]="noticeTypeOptions"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.noticeType.errors }" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code" appSingleSelection></p-dropdown>
                        <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.noticeType.errors && p.noticeType.errors?.error">
                            {{p.noticeType.errors?.error}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-6 p-lg-4 p-xl-3">
                <label for="noticeStartDate">Notice Start Date<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>                    
                <p-calendar [disabled]="isViewDisable" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy" [minDate]="minimumDate" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icon"
                formControlName="noticeStartDate" [(ngModel)]="noticeStartDate"
                [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.noticeStartDate.errors }" appDateSelection
                placeholder="Select the date">
            </p-calendar>
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.noticeStartDate.errors && p.noticeStartDate.errors?.error">
                {{p.noticeStartDate.errors?.error}}</div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-12">
                <label for="notice">Notice<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
                <p-editor [readonly]="isViewDisable" formControlName="noticeText" [(ngModel)]="noticeText" [style]="{'height':'320px'}"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && p.noticeText.errors }" #editor appRequired>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <select class="ql-size">
                                <option value="small"></option>
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option value="large"></option>
                                <option value="huge"></option>
                              </select>
                            <button class="ql-bold" aria-label="Bold"></button>
                            <button class="ql-italic" aria-label="Italic"></button>
                            <button class="ql-underline" aria-label="Underline"></button>
                            <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                                <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>                                    <select title="Text Alignment" class="ql-align" >
                                  <option selected>Gauche</option>
                                  <option value="center" label="Center"></option>
                                  <option value="right" label="Right"></option>
                                  <option value="justify" label="Justify"></option>
                                </select>            
                              </span>
                              <span class="ql-formats">
                                <button class="ql-link" aria-label="Link"></button>
                              </span>
                          </span>
                    </ng-template>

                </p-editor>
                <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && p.noticeText.errors && p.noticeText.errors?.error">
                            {{p.noticeText.errors?.error}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-12">
                <label>Attachment with Notice</label>
                <p-fileUpload class="notice-upload" [disabled]="isViewDisable" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, .doc, .docx, application/msword, .pdf, application/vnd.ms-excel"  multiple="true" fileLimit="5" #fileInput name="noticeAttachement[]" (change)="onFileSelect(fileInput)" [auto]="true" maxFileSize="2621440" chooseLabel="Choose File">
                </p-fileUpload>
                <p-table styleClass="p-datatable-sm p-datatable-gridlines common-datatable p-mt-2" #dt [autoLayout]="true">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">File Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>
                <p-table styleClass="p-datatable-sm p-datatable-gridlines common-datatable" #dt [value]="namedetails"
                    [autoLayout]="true">                    
                    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex">
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{rowData.name}}</td>
                            <td><button pButton type="button" [disabled]="isViewDisable" icon="pi pi-times"
                                    class="ui-button-danger p-button-primary remove-button" (click)="deleteFile(ri, rowData.fileCode)"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>
                <p-table styleClass="p-datatable-sm p-datatable-gridlines common-datatable" #dt [value]="storeKmlFile"
                    [autoLayout]="true">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-ri="rowIndex">
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{rowData.name}}</td>
                            <td><button pButton type="button" [disabled]="isViewDisable" icon="pi pi-times"
                                    class="ui-button-danger p-button-primary remove-button" (click)="removeEditFile(rowData)"></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ng-template>
                </p-table>
            </div>                
        </div>
  
        <div class="clearfix button-area">
            <button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Cancel" *ngIf="!isViewDisable" class="p-button p-button-secondary" routerLink="/notice-management/list-notices"></button>
            <button pButton pRipple type="submit" label="Submit" *ngIf="!isViewDisable" class="p-button p-button-primary"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix button-area" *ngIf="isViewDisable">
            <button pButton pRipple type="button" label="Back" *ngIf="isViewDisable" routerLink="/notice-management/list-notices"
                class="p-button p-button-secondary"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

TS:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.addNoticeForm.valid) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      if (this.storeKmlFile) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.storeKmlFile.length; i++) {
          formData.append('noticeAttachement', this.storeKmlFile[i]);
        }
      }
      if (this.mode === 'create') {
        delete this.noticeModel['companyRole'];
      }
      this.fileCodeValue = 0;
      formData.append('user', this.selecteduser.toString());
      formData.append('noticeType', this.selectedNoticeType.toString());
      formData.append('noticeStartDate', moment(this.noticeStartDate).format("MM-DD-YYYY"));
      formData.append('noticeText', this.noticeText);
      formData.append('noticeCode', this.noticeCode);
      if (!this.storeKmlFile) {
          formData.append('noticeAttachement', "");
      }
      if (this.mode === 'edit') {
        for (let i in this.fileCodes) {
          formData.append('fileCode', this.fileCodes[i].toString());
          }
      }
      this.noticeService.addNotice(ConstUrls.NoticeManagement.AddNotice, formData, this.mode).subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (data.isSuccessful === true) {
            this.displayModal = true;
            this.showError = false;
            let buttonData = this.buttonData;
            this.modalService.success(data.message[0].message, buttonData);
          } else if (data.isSuccessful === false) {
            this.message = [{ field: "", message: data.message[0].message}];
            this.objError = this.message;
            this.showError = true;
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
          }
        }, (error) => {
            this.message = [{ field: "", message: "error"}];
            this.objError = this.message;
            this.showError = true;
            window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        });
    }
     else {
      this.showError = false;
      this.scrollToErrorField();
    }
  }
```

**Note:**
Before submitting we need to check weather editor is blank or not. If its not blank or empty we should proceed with data submission.

Comment: could you please provide your form?

Comment: Add the form and submit function from the TS file in the question.

Comment: Hello,
I have added . If the editor is having no data that is already handled. But if user only enter space and submit that should not happen.
@ApoorvaChikara

Comment: Hello  @mrJQuery

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to create a helper function which checks whether the current string is empty or not. You can also try other methods too like creating a directive or pipe to validate the string entered by the user.

```
const validateEmptyString = (value: string) => {
   if (!value) return true;
}
```

Add this method to the TS file and pass all the string forms value through this. I think your specifically looking for the text-editor one, pass its value through this method and check if it passes the validation. If it fails in this case failing will return `true`, don't submit the form instead show error in the form.

Comment: The issue here is that noticeText: is having value if user is entering space as space is also an input. Also as we need to send the whole html to backend even if we are only giving one space html is there. refer example 1,2 and 3 above.
If html was not there i could have checked for the index 0 of noticeText and restricted space.

Comment: Can you tell me the validation you want to add for NoticeText?

Comment: If a user is only entering space and submitting its getting summitted.
Need to stop that. 

Note:
noticeText is a mandatory field that has already been handled.
My idea was to restrict user to enter space as first letter.
But the issue is once space is entered we are getting input as example 1,2 and 3.

Comment: The best way to handle this is creating a custom directive and add it to your input.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the plain text from p-editor using code below  and check string contains  empty spaces only, so that you use this value and trigger the validation

```
<p-editor (onTextChange)="returnIsStingContainsOnlySpaces($event)" formControlName="noticeText" [(ngModel)]="noticeText" #editor>

returnIsStingContainsOnlySpaces(event){
  var text = event.textValue;
   
  if (!/\S/.test(text)) {
    this.invalidText= true;
  } else {
    this.invalidText = false;
  }
}
```